# convert UNIX epoch time to ISO8601 in a stream of data with perl

Tags: perl, unix-timestamp, iso8601

I'm using an API with `curl --write-out '\n%{http_code}\t=%{time_total}s\n'` that provides the date information about the fields in *UNIX Epoch time* instead of *ISO8601*, which makes it difficult to understand what's going on.

##### Sample Input:

```
{"message":"Domains list","list":[{"domain":"example.org","created":"1443042000","regtill":"1632430800"}]}
200 =0.126406s
```

```
{"list":[{"d":"abc","c":"1443042000"},{"d":"xyz","c":"1000000000"}]}
200 =0.126406s
```

Is there a way to find in this stream of data anything that looks like a UNIX Epoch time (e.g., representing the recent times (any 10-digit number in quotes should do (`1000000000` is `2001-09-09` as per `env TZ=GMT-3 date -r1000000000 +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z` with [BSD `date(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/date.1)))), and convert it all to ISO8601-like dates, with a small shell script snippet in `perl` or BSD `awk` without any extensive dependencies to do the transformation?

##### Desired Output (with or without timezone offsets):

```
{"message":"Domains list","list":[
    {"domain":"example.org","created":"2015-09-24T000000+0300","regtill":"2021-09-24T000000+0300"}]}
200 =0.126406s
```

```
{"list":[
    {"d":"abc","c":"2015-09-24T000000+0300"},
    {"d":"xyz","c":"2001-09-09T044640+0300"}]}
200 =0.126406s
```

Comment: Yes, basically any number that has 10 digits and is enclosed in quotes.

Comment: What have you tried? Any specific issues you're having? Also, there are two questions here: how to find the UNIX epoch times, and how to convert them. The second one has been asked many times before. (and the first one is "how to find a 10-digit number bellow 4.2 billion?", which has _probably_ already been asked before)

Comment: `$ perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/(\d{10,})/{localtime($1)->datetime}/ge' <<<'{"message":"Domains list","list":[{"domain":"example.org","created":"1443042000","regtill":"1632430800"}]}'` - you can pipe your `curl` through this.

Comment: @simbabque, perfect, thank you!  Exactly what I was looking for!  Works without any extra tools or packages to install!  Can you post this as an answer?  I'll accept.

Comment: Except it doesn't actually work. It replaces things it shouldn't (e.g. for numbers, string literals of the form `"0000000000"`, string literals of the form `"a1234567890"` and strings literals of the form `"\u2660000000"`) and it doesn't replace stuff it should (e.g. string literals of the form `"12345\u00367890"`). One of those examples even produces invalid JSON!

Comment: @ikegami that's a minor detail; improvements with backtracking and/or deliniation on `"` are welcome. :)

Comment: Also, simbabque's solution provides local times with no offsets, which are useless.

Comment: @cnst  Re "*Fixing these involves writing or better yet using a JSON parser.*", You're asking me to write a JSON parser? That's not going to happen. You could use an existing one, then walk the resulting tree, applying fixes where necessary. I've already shown exactly how to do exactly that in a simple manner.

Comment: Aside from specifying exactly what values in the JSON data you want to reformat, I'd use the JSON, DateTime and DateTime::Format::ISO8601 modules from CPAN

Comment: @ikegami you could start `perl` with `env TZ=GMT-3` to ensure the correct offset; I don't understand why this question was closed when the solution is posted in a comment.

Comment: @glennjackman any value that's a 10-digit number enclosed by quotes

Comment: `env TZ=GMT-3` doesn't help the issue I raised. /// I I already covered that there is no solution in the comments.  /// Solutions should not be posted in the comments. /// The question wasn't closed for lack of solution; the questions was closed because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @ikegami why use an external json parser when a simple perl script does the job?  Why local times with no offsets is a problem?  The problem with external parser is that multiple JSON requests, all piped, might not work anymore, because it won't be a valid JSON anymore; note that the question doesn't specify that the data is actually a JSON.  Also, I'm not requesting code-writing, I'm looking for a snippet on how to transfor a stream of data; the solution provided in the comments does the job exactly as requested.

Comment: Re "*why use an external json parser when a simple perl script does the job?*", I don't now what you mean by "external". But you need a parse by definition. The question is whether it's a broken one or not. A simple Perl script that would do the job would be nice, but that's not possible with core Perl, meaning you'd have to install a module if such a module even exists. There is a JSON parser in core, but navigating the JSON structure to find the values to modify is not simple.

Comment: @ikegami but it is possible -- the correct answer is in the comments above.  It works on any stream of data.  Does jq work on two json outputs concatenated together?  `python -m json.tool`, for example, doesn't; which is why it might make sense to pretty-print the data with `perl`, too.

Comment: You are mistaken. I pointed out 5 bugs with the above program, include the fact that it generated invalid JSON.

Comment: Re "*Does jq work on two json outputs concatenated together?*", It does in general, and the solution I provided does specifically.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying you can't or shouldn't use Perl, and I'm not saying you should use jq; I'm just saying that you can do what you want do simply without installing something.

Comment: I put this code in the comments as a pointer to what could be done. While I was trying that out, the question was closed. I didn't claim it would make the JSON actually work, but I understood the question as "I don't care about the JSON, I just want to read the values". @ikegami is right of course, it's not a production-ready solution at all. But I didn't claim it would be.

Comment: @simbabque Exactly, no revision of my question ever made any mention of input or output being valid json; in fact, if you try to make more than one request with curl, or have any extra output, then all the other solutions likely won't work, not to mention that they require extra software to be installed above the base system.  Sad the question has been taken over by all the json purists; feel free to repost your comment as a gen answer, I'll accept, and it's the one I'll be using (see my answer).  I'll be happy to accept and upvote yours if you re-post; thanks a bunch for the simple snippet!

Comment: I think you should reword your question a bit more. If all you want to do is make the timestamps readable for one-off human consumption, without requiring further processing to work, and without caring about the rest of the data or whether the integrity of the format will be retained, and without installing extra software, then you should say so. Otherwise the other answers indeed address the generic "how do I convert this data on the fly?" issue. Your question can still be understood to mean "how do I put extra processing in without breaking my data?". I think that's the main issue argued atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best snippet so far has been provided by simbabque in a comment:

> `$ perl -MTime::Piece -pe 's/(\d{10,})/{localtime($1)->datetime}/ge' <<<'{"message":"Domains list","list":[{"domain":"example.org","created":"1443042000","regtill":"1632430800"}]}'` - you can pipe your curl through this. –
> simbabque 1 hour ago

---

I've further adapted it as follows:

- modified the regular expression to use positive lookbehind and lookahead, for `\w":"` (word, quote, colon, quote) and `"\W{2}` (quote, not word twice), with `(?<=\w":")` and `(?="\W{2})`, respectively, to match UNIX Epoch time only as a JSON value of some keyword, and avoid any possible false-positives when random other data is streamed into the script;
- restrict UNIX Epoch time to exactly 10-digits, which should cover date periods between 2001 and 2286:

  - `env TZ=GMT perl -MTime::Piece -e 'print localtime(1000000000)->datetime, "Z/", localtime(9999999999)->datetime, "Z\n"'`
  - `2001-09-09T01:46:40Z/2286-11-20T17:46:39Z`
- use a few extra regular expressions to insert line breaks for each entry of the domain array;

The simplest snippet:

```
curl ... \ 
  | perl -MTime::Piece -pe's#(\d{10})#localtime($1)->datetime#ge'
```

Add lookbehind/lookahead for just the opening/closing quote symbols alone:

```
curl ... \ 
  | perl -MTime::Piece -pe's#(?<=")(\d{10})(?=")#localtime($1)->datetime#ge'
```

Specify the timezone of the input data, more restrictive JSON-specific lookbehind/lookahead, and also insert linebreaks for each domain in the list, to make it more user-readable:

```
curl ... \ 
  | env TZ=GMT-3 perl -MTime::Piece -p \
    -e 's#(?<=":\[|["\d]},)(?={")#\n\t#g;' \
    -e 's#(?<=\w":")(\d{10})(?="\W{2})#localtime($1)->datetime#ge;'
```

Sample test run of the final solution for the overall transformation -- works on any stream of data, ignores anything that's not a JSON, would never give any errors on invalid JSON:

```
% printf '{"list":[{"d":"abc","c":"1443042000"},{"d":"xyz","c":"1000000000"}]}\n' \
    | env TZ=GMT-3 perl -MTime::Piece -p \
    -e 's#(?<=":\[|["\d]},)(?={")#\n\t#g;' \
    -e 's#(?<=\w":")(\d{10})(?="\W{2})#localtime($1)->datetime#ge;'
{"list":[
    {"d":"abc","c":"2015-09-24T00:00:00"},
    {"d":"xyz","c":"2001-09-09T04:46:40"}]}
%
```

---

This solution is more flexible than the other solutions that presume that the input is a valid JSON, because it can also be used in instances where a single `curl` command is used to make more than a single request, which wouldn't be a valid JSON, since JSON can only have one root element.  It also works with `curl --write-out` (e.g., `curl -w '\n%{http_code}\t=%{time_total}s\n'`), which, likewise, would not be valid JSON, either.  It's also more flexible because it doesn't even assume that the input data is in any specific format -- anything with the 10-digit numbers between `\w":"` and `"\W{2}` will be automatically converted from *UNIX Epoch time* to *ISO8601* exactly as specified in the question.

Comment: This still fails for a number of  input patterns. Also, the solution also can't be used for any time zone that has Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: I recommend clearing up the confusion. It leads with even something you agree isn't good. It's the followed by what is effectively a long list of reasons what that initial code block isn't good. None of that needs to be there.

Comment: Re "*I don't understand why you keep insisting that the solution I chose is wrong when in fact it's the more fitting for the problem at stake!*", I actually said it doesn't work. And gave examples.

Comment: @ikegami why are you downvoting perfectly valid solutions that actually solve the problem?  This solution does NOT suffer from any of the issues you've previously identified for the original snippet that I found to be the most useful; and most of the world also does not use DST, so, there's no issue with DST ambiguity for `TZ=GMT-3`, either. In all, this is still the best solution that does exactly what the title of this question requires!  No, I absolutely do NOT agree that the initial block of code isn't good -- it was still the most useful comment/hint out of this whole question!

Comment: @ikegami as for removing "list of reasons" the "initial code block isn't good" from the answer, i'm very surprised by such a request, because I thought the whole purpose of StackOverflow is not just provide useful and reusable code snippets, but also explain exactly how they work.  This solution does exactly that.  Your own solution has no explanation of anything; and also doesn't work on the "stream of data".  Please read the title of the question again, and stop shoving JSON down people's throats.  The question was clearly clear enough for another user to provide the exact code that works.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jq, a great tool for manipulating JSON.

```sh
jq '
   ( .. | select(type == "string") | select(try tonumber | . > 1000000000) ) |=
      ( tonumber | todateiso8601 )
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1NrtfBn-Ln)

Comment: This requires an extra tool to be installed; `jq` isn't included with the base OpenBSD system, but `perl` and BSD `awk` are.

Comment: Conversely, `perl` and `jq` can be installed on Windows, but not `awk`.

Comment: awk can be installed on Windows just fine, e.g. see http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm.

Comment: ah nice. I knew you could install it in unix emulation environments on Windows (e.g, Cygwin and MSYS), but this is the first time I've heard of a port. Sorry, I should have checked.

Comment: I never use it myself except on such a Unix emulation environment so while I knew it existed for Windows I'm surprised that's such an old version (from 2008!) of gawk on that site. I suspect there's a newer version somewhere but idk where and am too lazy to look for it.

Comment: I've tried `jq` on another machine that had it installed; and although it does appear to work for contactenated json where more than a single element is available at root (unlike `python -m json.tool`, which returns an error), it doesn't work if there is any other output around individually valid json strings, or if input is not a json at all.  Please note that at no point did the question specify that input or output is a valid json -- the question simply gave one as an example, but the question itself is about a stream of data, needing to be transformed in shell with the shortest snippet.

Comment: It was either assuming the input was JSON, or vote to close the question for insufficient info. Can't parse something without knowing the format

Comment: It was literally the first clarification I've added -- any 10-digit numbers enclosed within quotes need to be translated from UNIX Epoch time to ISO8601!  I don't understand why you keep insisting that the solution I chose is wrong when in fact it's the more fitting for the problem at stake!  And when the requirement is perl or awk, not third-party newer tools that don't work on random data!  Really-really zero interest in valid JSON on my side here!  Let's just stop this whole JSON debate already!  You've posted a great solution, but for a slightly different question.

Comment: No, you did not provide the data's format. You gave a sample, which you have since said isn't representative of what you actually have without further clarification. So it's completely useless. Feel free to fix the question if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perl script that reads your JSON on standard input so it can have `curl` output piped to it:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/say/;
use experimental qw/postderef/;
use Time::Piece;
# Install through your OS package manager if provided or favorite
# CPAN client. Or use a different JSON module you like better; perl
# has quite a few available. Worst case if you can't install any
# extra modules is to use core JSON::PP
use JSON::MaybeXS; 

my $json = JSON::MaybeXS->new->utf8;

my $rawdata = do { local $/; <STDIN> };
my $data = $json->decode($rawdata);

for my $domain ($data->{list}->@*) {
    $domain->{created} = localtime($domain->{created})->datetime;
    $domain->{regtill} = localtime($domain->{regtill})->datetime;
}

say $json->encode($data);
```

Example:

```sh
$ ./convtimes < input.json
{"message":"Domains list","list":[{"created":"2015-09-23T14:00:00","regtill":"2021-09-23T14:00:00","domain":"example.org"}]}
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify that the input is a valid JSON.  This also doesn't seem to work because not all version of perl have experimental?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script is not great, but it does produce the expected output (maybe with a few flaws?).

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=":|,"; OFS=":"; RS="["
} NR==1 {
    $NF="["
}  NR>1 {
    gsub(/"/,"");
    $4=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z",$4);
    $6=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z}]}",$6);
    gsub(/:/,"\":\"");
    sub(/{/,"{\"");
    sub(/}/,"}\"")
} 1
```

Or as a one liner

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=":|,"; OFS=":"; RS="["} NR==1 {$NF="["}  NR>1 {gsub(/"/,""); $4=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z",$4);$6=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z}]}",$6); gsub(/:/,"\":\""); sub(/{/,"{\""); sub(/}/,"}\"")}1' input_file
```

**Output**

```
{"message":"Domains list":"list":[
{"domain":"example.org":"created":"2015-09-23T220000+0100":"regtill":"2021-09-23T220000+0100}"]}
```

Comment: Thanks!  It doesn't look like it works in the BSD `awk`, though (gives out an error), but does seem to work in `gawk`.  However, it appears to depend on the certain positioning of the UNIX Epoch time elements within JSON, so, it does work on the original sample input, but won't work in the general case -- not a Google-friendly solution, but might be a starting point for someone.

Answer (score -1):

Use the date command.  This command:
`date -d '@1443042000'`
Produces this answer:
`Wed 23 Sep 2015 03:00:00 PM MDT`

Comment: The correct command on BSD and macOS is `date -r1443042000 +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S%z`, but it's of little help because it cannot be automated on a stream of text.